# lateinit property list has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit, rx-java

I have used Retrofit, RxJava and RecyclerView on the project and a problem has occurred immediately. Here the isMainActivity.kt file:

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var list: List<Data>
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerviewAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter=RecyclerviewAdapter(list)
        binding.recyclerview.adapter= adapter
        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }
```

I am trying to access those Datas:

```
data class Data(var date : Date?, var temperatureC: Int?,var temperatureF:Int?, var summary:String?){
}
```

and the error is here:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.httpclient, PID: 26086
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.httpclient/view.MainActivity}:
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property list
> has not been initialized
>    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
>    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
>    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
>    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>    at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
>
> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit
> property list has not been initialized
>    at view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)
>    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
>    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
>    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)

I expect to see how it works.

Comment: You never created the list. The error message tells you exactly what’s wrong.

Comment: in onCreate() say list = listOf()

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you initialize your list anywhere, you need to assign an empty list before using

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Add here
    list = listOf<Data>()
    adapter=RecyclerviewAdapter(list)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initailizing the list property in onCreate() method.
You have to initaizlize it like:

```
list = List<Data>?
```

Then pass it to

```
adapter=RecyclerviewAdapter(list)
```